# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

Tags: android

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación móvil, estoy usando lo que es menú lateral. Cuento con un botón flotante el cual se espera sea como un carrito de compras. Al ejecutar la aplicación en el dispositivo virtual, me aparece el siguiente error:

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.creps/com.example.creps.Home}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12 in com.example.creps:layout/activity_home: Binary XML file line #25 in com.example.creps:layout/app_bar_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.

Tengo mucho tiempo tratando de solucionarlo, pero no he encontrado la manera.

Aquí mi *layout/app_bar_main*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Home">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextStyle"
            app:popupTheme="@style/PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
        android:tint="@android:color/black"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_shopping_cart_24"
        tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Mi *build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.creps"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //Add Library
    implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.4'
    implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
    implementation'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    implementation'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    implementation'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha01'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

este se produce al inflar el FloatingActionButton , la definición de la clase es correcta pero el problema seguramente es un recurso que cargas para este elemento, generalmente el problema son las imagenes, en este caso hay que revisar esta linea `app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_shopping_cart_24"` :.

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
    android:tint="@android:color/black"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_shopping_cart_24"
    tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />
```

con respecto a la imagen "ic_baseline_shopping_cart_24", revisa si es un vector asset y muy importante, que esta se encuentre en el directorio `/drawable` de tu proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

una solucion es cambiar `app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_shopping_cart_24"` a:

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_shopping_cart_24"
```

Otra es seguir usando `app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_shopping_cart_24"`
y agregar el soporte para los vector drawable en el gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.creps"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    ....
```